# VBA - Formula does not appear in cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write a formula using vba and pass a string to that argument.

Now I've got this:

`ActiveCell.Offset(2, 2).Formula = "=INDIRECT(""'"" &$A$7& ""'!"" &ADDRESS(4;MATCH($A$8;Status!$A$1:$Q$1;0)))"`

But nothing appears in that cell.

Can you give me some help?

Thanks!

Comment: It works! Can you explain why? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Let me add that this also applies for decimals, formula names and date formats. VBA always uses the US English format, and Excel does the localization. E.g. the VBA code: =SUM(1.5,2.2) produces this in in a cell in Hungarian Excel: =SZUM(1,5;2,2).

Answer (score 1):

You can either write your formula using English format, as mentioned in comments by pnuts and vacip, or use [`Range.FormulaLocal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838851(v=office.15).aspx) instead of `Range.Formula` to write it in your locale, but it might cause problems if you open the workbook on another computer with different locale.